# 12 Factor approach and client-side web app

Tags: ember.js, 12factor

This question is terribly open-ended, but are there any resources which discuss the 12 Factor approach to a (one-page) client-side Javascript application? Even better if it considers a 12 Factor approach to building a web app with EmberJS.

Comment: For others who stumble upon this question: https://adrianperez.org/12-factoring-single-page-applications/